# Time to display OS and time to display recovery options

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, operating-system

I really enjoy automating things to make life easier for my self.  I have tried looking around on this site as well as just Googling my question but nothing has come up to even point me in the right direction.  So here is my question.  I would like to:

1. Disable (aka uncheck) Time to display list of operating system.
2. Set Time to display recovery options when needed to 3 seconds.

If it is possible to make this happen within a vbscript or a batch file that would be great.  I will continue my search my self, but if anyone could help that would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcdedit is the tool on Vista to modify boot entries.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886.aspx is a bcdedit FAQ.

```
bcdedit /timeout 0
```

should effectively disable the OS selection screen.

I don't know how to set the recovery options to 3 seconds, you can do this via the Startup and Recovery UI, but no clear way via bcdedit.